# Pytest, how can i make an action depending on session result?

Tags: python, pytest

I would like to post a notification about result of whole session and not each test explicity as in:
- I've got 10 tests
- If at least one of them fail post a notification: Test session failed
- If all passed, post a notification : test session passed

For the record, i only have problem with setting it up in pytest. To call something on the end of session depending on result.

Comment: I actually made it myself by adding to conftest.py variable and function as:

`import pytest

countFailedTests = 0

def addToCountFailedTests():
 global countFailedTests
 countFailedTests += 1

@pytest.hookimpl(tryfirst=True, hookwrapper=True)
def pytest_runtest_makereport():
 outcome = yield
 rep = outcome.get_result()

 if rep.when == 'call' and rep.passed:
  pass
 elif rep.when == 'call' and rep.failed:
  addToCountFailedTests()`

and simply imported countFailedTests in my teardown_module() function and used that to define behavior on end of tests.